# Maximal rank definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

What would it be to say that a linear map $T:\mathbb R^{m+n}\longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$ has maximal rank?

I'd like a precise definition of it, I skimmed several linear algebra books after the definition but I didn't find it.

If someone could recommend me a reference which defines it I would be glad=)

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what the rank of a linear map is?

Comment: Yes, that is the dimension of the range of $T$..

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$. A linear map $T:V \to W$ has *maximal rank* there is no linear map $T’ : V \to W$ such that $\operatorname{rank}(T) < \operatorname{rank}(T’)$.

If $\dim V \leq \dim W$ then a linear map of maximal rank must have rank equal to $\dim V$. If $\dim V \geq \dim W$ then a linear map of maximal rank must have rank equal to $\dim W$.

Answer (score 0):

The rank of a linear transformation $T$ is the dimension of the image of $T$, that is, the dimension of the set $$\{T(\alpha) \ | \ \alpha  \ \text{is in the domain of $T$} )\}.$$ This set can be proved to be a subspace of the range of $T$. Now in your case, $T$ is mapped to $\Bbb R^n$. Note that if $A$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$, then $\dim A \le \dim V$. And also note that $\dim \Bbb R^n = n$. I think you can formulate for yourself what is meant by maximal dimension here. I don't think it's a standard term, though, to be found in books.